# Booting Ubuntu Core without external network

Tags: networking, network-manager, ubuntu-core

I am unable to boot Ubuntu Core without having an external network.
It requires a network that assigns a IP address eventhough the network might not be connected to the internet.

What I have tried:

a. Configuring the netplan configuration files in /etc/netplan/00-snapd-config.yaml to configure a wireless AP in order to create an access point and assign a IP address to work around this issue.

b. Assigning a static IP address in the same file /etc/netplan/00-snapd-config.yaml .

Is there any work around the booting process requiring an external network?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: AFAIK, the only "workaround" is to not use Ubuntu Core, but instead use Ubuntu Server install, for example. Ubuntu Core is not a traditional Linux install, and is designed to be used on remote managed devices, such as IoT.

Comment: @dobey I have managed to boot without an external network by assigning a static IP and marking the device as optional in the netplan configuration files, I have a ongoing discussion here: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/booting-ubuntu-core-without-external-network/4863/7